# What's the difference between "Google App Engine Flexible project", "Standard project" and "Dataflow project"

Tags: google-eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-tools

After installing Google Plugin for Eclipse, there are options to create three different types of projects

1. Google App Engine Flexible Java Project
2. Google App Engine Standard Java Project
3. Google Dataflow Java Project

What is the difference between these three?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) allows you to deploy application with minimum infrastructure related configuration. Standard is quicker in both deploying and scaling your application, but has a limited choice of languages and libraries to use. Flexible manages docker containers so it can run almost anything and has more powerful machines to chose from, same that Compute Engine has, but it takes longer to deploy and is in general more expensive.

Lightweight generic code that should be always available should run on Standard. A batch job that is processed once every day and requires an expensive setup and third party libraries would better run on Flex.

More on that [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/flexible-for-standard-users)

> Google App Engine Dataflow Java Project

It's not an App Engine, it says:

> Google App Engine Dataflow Java Project

It's a service directed specifically at batch jobs and streaming. More on it [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/).